# Is it possible to restrict display item under grouped field in the Document Library

Tags: document-library

I have a library which is grouped by "field1" and I would like that each grouped section display just 3 latest entries.

Is it possible?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve this using OOTB views. You have to use client side customization to achieve this. 
If you are using SP 2010, you need to use jsom to get require view.

If you have SP 2013, JSLink should be a great view to start...it will allow you to customize your list view webpart. there is groupby template override which has to be used to override group template.

Js link reference...
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/13/sharepoint-2013-js-link-tutorial/

Assuming you have gone through jslink samples at link above.

Override group template using following line of JS code-

```
overrideCtx.Templates.Group = CustomGroup;
```

Add following function which will change the group rendering-

```
function CustomGroup(ctx, group, groupId, listItem, listSchema, level, expand) {

var html = '<div style="font-weight:bold">' + listItem[group] + ' :: </div>';

return html;

}
```

You might also want to look at CSR,

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/620110/sharepoint-client-side-rendering-list-views -  this is very good which explains step by step of using CSR